# multi-level bulletpoints

Tags: bullets

I can write:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item Juice
\item Coffee
\end{itemize}
```

However, I would like to sub-divide Coffee further and get a result

[image]

The sub-items of Coffee are marked with different bulletpoints and additional indentation.

How to implement that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you show is the default behaviour for latex lists:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Juice
    \item Cofee
        \begin{itemize}
            \item With milk
            \item Without milk
        \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The bulletpoints are not different in beamer. @samcarter ?

Answer (score 3):

Use package `enumitem`

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=$\bullet$]
    \item Juice
    \item Cofee
        \begin{enumerate}[label=$ - $]
            \item With miklk
            \item Without milk
        \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The label you can choose by key `label =`.

Comment: You can just use `itemize` instead